# Combining Hashtables without unifying interface

Tags: java, hashmap, hashtable

For a lot of implementation reasons (Using Java ME 1.4 with *very* limited libraries), I have no access to HashMap or any kind of Map interface. In combination with this, I have to use Hashtable, which in the libraries I'm using does not inherit anything.

Yes, there is absolutely no way for me to get around the implementation and libraries that I'm using.

So I have two Hashtables. I need to make one new Hashtable instance that accesses and changes the two "backing" instances. Since Hashtable does not inherit anything, is there any way I could do this? I've tried a rudimentary composing strategy that just goes through an array of tables, but there are some serious problems with that. Specifically, `put(key, object)` is difficult because there's no way to tell which map it is being backed to.

Any suggestions on a strategy to do this or am I stuck?

```
public class Scope {

    private final Hashtable publicVars;
    private final Hashtable publicMethods;
    private final Hashtable publicReturning;
    private final Hashtable privateVars;
    private final Hashtable privateMethods;

    public Scope() {
        publicMethods = new Hashtable();
        publicReturning = new Hashtable(0);
        publicVars = new Hashtable();
        privateVars = new Hashtable();
        privateMethods = new Hashtable();
    }

    public Scope(Scope scope) {
        publicVars = scope.publicVars;
        publicMethods = scope.publicMethods;
        publicReturning = scope.publicReturning;
        privateVars = new Hashtable();
        privateMethods = new Hashtable();

        // Here's my problem - I need changes made to publicVars to also affect scope.privateVars (and the same to methods)
        publicVars.putAll(scope.privateVars);
        publicMethods.putAll(scope.privateMethods);
    }
```

Comment: Well, if there is no way of telling which `Map` to `put` into then there is no way of telling. _You_ need to define a strategy for that. Or make the unified `HashTable` immutable.

Comment: Why are you making one Hashtable which updates two Hashtables?  Why not have one Hashtable used in two places?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve with this 'combined Hashtable'?

Comment: I need one hashtable to "push" updates "upstream" to it's "parent" hashtables. Does that make any sense? I'm probably approaching this wrong.

Comment: I added an example to hopefully clarify what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to implement a variable scope chain as in Javascript.  The rules for what gets returnd and/or updated or created, and where, are unambiguously defined in JS, as they should be in your system.  You must decide what those rules are and then the implementation should be quite natural.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private static final class MapGroup {

    private final List maps = new ArrayList();

    public MapGroup(Hashtable start) {
        maps.add(start);
    }

    public MapGroup(MapGroup group) {
        for (int x = 0; x < group.maps.size(); x++) {
            maps.add(group.maps.get(x));
        }
    }

    public void add(Hashtable h) {
        maps.add(h);
    }

    public Enumeration keys() {
        return new Enumeration() {
            private final Enumeration[] enumerations;
            private int i;

            {
                enumerations = new Enumeration[maps.size()];
                for (int x = 0; x < maps.size(); x++) {
                    enumerations[x] = ((Hashtable) maps.get(x)).keys();
                }
            }

            public boolean hasMoreElements() {
                return enumerations[i].hasMoreElements()
                        || (++i < enumerations.length && enumerations[i].hasMoreElements());
            }

            public Object nextElement() {
                // needed to increment i
                return hasMoreElements() ? enumerations[i].nextElement() : null;
            }
        };
    }

    public Enumeration elements() {
        return new Enumeration() {
            private final Enumeration[] enumerations;
            private int i;

            {
                enumerations = new Enumeration[maps.size()];
                for (int x = 0; x < maps.size(); x++) {
                    enumerations[x] = ((Hashtable) maps.get(x)).elements();
                }
            }

            public boolean hasMoreElements() {
                return enumerations[i].hasMoreElements()
                        || (++i < enumerations.length && enumerations[i].hasMoreElements());
            }

            public Object nextElement() {
                // needed to increment i
                return hasMoreElements() ? enumerations[i].nextElement() : null;
            }
        };
    }

    public boolean contains(Object value) {
        for (int x = 0; x < maps.size(); x++) {
            if (((Hashtable) maps.get(x)).contains(value)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public boolean containsKey(Object key) {
        for (int x = 0; x < maps.size(); x++) {
            if (((Hashtable) maps.get(x)).containsKey(key)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public Object get(Object key) {
        for (int x = 0; x < maps.size(); x++) {
            if (((Hashtable) maps.get(x)).containsKey(key)) {
                return ((Hashtable) maps.get(x)).get(key);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public Object put(Object key, Object value) {
        for (int x = 0; x < maps.size(); x++) {
            if (((Hashtable) maps.get(x)).containsKey(key)) {
                return ((Hashtable) maps.get(x)).put(key, value);
            }
        }
        return ((Hashtable) maps.get(maps.size() - 1)).put(key, value);
    }

    public Object remove(Object key) {
        // Nothing is ever removed - don't worry
        return null;
    }

    public void clear() {
    }

    public int size() {
        int s = 0;
        for (int x = 0; x < maps.size(); x++) {
            s += ((Hashtable) maps.get(x)).size();
        }
        return s;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return size() == 0;
    }
}
```

Thanks for making me have to think about this guys. I wrote this and it works for me.